# Runtime or compile time for platform-specific libraries?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, jit, llvm, platform-specific

I'm creating a library in C++. It links against Windows libraries on Windows and Linux libraries on Linux. It's abstracted, all is well.

However, is it feasible to dynamically detect, load and use libraries (and copying header files for use) so it could be used on any platform if it was running under LLVM JIT?

Comment: What do you mean by detect? do you mean find?

Comment: I mean find and load in to memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the LLVM intermediate representation in the bitcode files is not machine completely machine independent. You could probably get away with x86 Linux and Windows, but that same bitcode would probably not run on x86_64 systems, for example.